# Improper integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-ax-by}} \,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ such that $a^2+b^2 = 1$

We wish to determine whether this integral converges, and if it does, calculate it:

$\int_D \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-ax-by}}\,dx\,dy$ where $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2+y^2<1\}$

Since the domain is a circle it would make a lot of sense to transform it to $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-ar\cos\theta-br\sin\theta}}\,d\theta \, dr$$

But this function does not have an anti derivative (where theta is the variable and $r$ is contant).

If we change the order of integration, we get something equally unpleasant. I tried integrating by parts but that didn't lead me anywhere.

How do we calculate this integral?

Comment: $a\cos \theta + b\sin \theta = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \cos (\theta - \phi)$ and since $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and $\phi$ becomes irrelevant when you integrate around the full circle.  $\iint \frac {r}{\sqrt {1-r\cos\theta}} \ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: What is $\phi$? and why is this true? I don't think I've ever seen this identity.

Comment: $\phi = \arctan \frac {b}{a}, \frac {a}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}} = \cos \phi, \frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}} = \sin\phi, a\cos\theta + b\sin \theta = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}( \cos\theta\cos\phi + \sin\theta\sin \phi)$

Comment: You can try the series expansion for $(1-z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ with $z = r\cos(\theta+\theta_0)$ and then integrate the series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exploiting the constraint $a^2+b^2=1$. You may assume $a=\cos\varphi$ and $b=\sin\varphi$, hence by switching to polar coordinates your integral becomes

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho\sin(\theta+\varphi)}}\,d\theta\,d\rho =  \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1-\rho\sin\theta}}\,d\theta\,d\rho$$
or, by Fubini's theorem,
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2}{3\sin^2\theta}\left[2-\sqrt{1-\sin\theta}\,(2+\sin\theta)\right]\,d\theta = 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2}{3\cos^2\theta}\left[2-\sqrt{1-\cos\theta}\,(2+\cos\theta)\right]\,d\theta $$
which simplifies into $\frac{8}{3}\sqrt{2}$ through the tangent half-angle substitution. Anyway, it is much simpler to exploit the independence from $\varphi$ and just assume $(a,b)=(1,0)$.

Comment: I've seen this integral now and i got to this $\iint \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r(\cos(\theta-\phi)}}$ and i don't see how you got to $\sin(\theta+\phi)$

Comment: @ronkurman: $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta-\phi)$ are related to each other via a simple translation, they both are $2\pi$-periodic functions of the $\theta$ variable.